# Connection Refused: when trying to build remotely it attempts to connect to port 8000 instead of 8980 specified during bootstrap

Tags: build, chromium, bazel, bazel-rules

In `first screen` started the `local build` :

```
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~/chromium-original/chromium/src/buildtools/reclient/bb-deployments# bazel run //bare -- /root/tmp/bb-cache
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Analyzed target //bare:bare (733 packages loaded, 19013 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //bare:bare up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/bare/bare_/bare
INFO: Elapsed time: 21.606s, Critical Path: 1.87s
INFO: 1 process: 1 internal.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
INFO: Running command line: bazel-bin/bare/bare_/bare /root/tmp/bb-cache
2023/10/09 16:41:39 Don't worry if you see some "Failed to synchronize with scheduler" warnings on startup
2023/10/09 16:41:39     - they should stop once bb_scheduler is ready
2023/10/09 16:41:39 Started bb_storage with PID 2472
2023/10/09 16:41:39 Started bb_storage with PID 2473
2023/10/09 16:41:39 Started bb_scheduler with PID 2480
2023/10/09 16:41:39 Started bb_worker with PID 2489
2023/10/09 16:41:39 Started bb_runner with PID 2495
2023/10/09 16:41:39 Started bb_browser with PID 2498
```

In `second screen` bootstrapped ReProxy , specifying the port `8980` :

```
  root@k8s-eu-1-master:~/chromium-original/chromium/src/buildtools/reclient/bb-deployments/bare# ../../bootstrap -re_proxy=../../reproxy -server_address=127.0.0.1:8980 -service_no_auth=true
  Proxy started successfully.
```

In `third screen`, tried, but, **failed**, **to start** `remote building`:
strangely, it attempts to connect to port 8080 instead of 8980

```
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~/chromium-original/chromium/src/buildtools/reclient/bb-deployments/bare# ../../rewrapper -platform=OSFamily=linux,ISA=x86-64,docker=//gcr.io/cloud-marketplace/google/rbe-ubuntu16-04@sha256:b4dad0bfc4951d619229ab15343a311f2415a16ef83bcaa55b44f4e2bf1cf635 -exec_strategy="remote_local_fallback" -dial_timeout="10m" -exec_root="/root/chromium-original/chromium/src" -- bazel run //bare -- /root/tmp/bb-cache/
F1009 16:48:41.651345    4790 main.go:175] Command failed: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = retry budget exhausted (10 attempts): connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8000: connect: connection refused"
```

OS: Ubuntu 22.04

How to make it work?